# Firebase Storage downloadURL or downloadURLs?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

When I work with Firebase Storage I use `downloadURL` file metadata to access the file. But the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata) says it's `downloadURLs`. Is that a typo?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It says that downloadURLs is an Array of strings.

From experience, Firebase lets you [create new Download Urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXTME.png) so that single files can have multiple download URLs.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.FullMetadata#downloadURLs) that the `downloadURLs` variable is:

> An array of long-lived download URLs. Always contains at least one
>   URL.

[`downloadURL`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot#downloadURL) is a different variable. If you get the `downloadURL` programmatically using [`getDownloadUrl()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url), it will generate a new url that will be added to the downloadURLs array. But if you get it from the `metadata`, it will give you an URL that already exists on that array.